# Schema Ratings/Review Count

Tags: schema.org, rich-snippets, review

I am implementing schema ratings and reviews on the same page. Users can add a star rating or add a review with a star rating. When this happens I combining the two and outputtng the ratingvalue.

I can get them both working using the google data testing tool with reviewCount or ratingCount. Though I am wondering which is better to use, the reviewCount or ratingCount, or it doesn't matter?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Both are different.

**reviewCount:** The count of total number of reviews.

**ratingCount:** The count of total number of ratings.

Please refer [here](http://schema.org/AggregateRating) for further details

Comment: Dear downvoter, may I know the reason why? It would be better if you explain the reason of downvote

Answer (score 1):

**`ratingCount`:** The total **number of ratings** for the item on your site. At least one of `ratingCount` or `reviewCount` is required.

**`reviewCount`:** Specifies the number of people who provided a **review with or without an accompanying rating**. At least one of `ratingCount` or `reviewCount` is required.

Source: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/reviews